# How can I call a Pinned future from an actix handler?

Tags: rust, async-await, future, rust-actix

I have an async trait method which returns a std Future:

```rust
Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = Result<Vec<ResultType>, Box<(dyn Error + 'static)>>> + Send>>
```

`ResultType` is an associated type of the trait which is `Sync + Send`.

Note that this type **is not Unpin**.

I want to call this from an actix handler, then do something with the result.

For example:

```rust
impl StreamHandler<ws::Message, ws::ProtocolError> for MyActor {
    fn handle(&mut self, msg: ws::Message) {
        let fut = get_future();
        let actor_fut = fut
            .into_actor(&self)
            .map(|r, _actor, ctx| {
                ctx.text(r.map(|| ...))
            });

        ctx.spawn(actor_fut);
    }
}
```

This fails because `into_actor` takes ownership of the future, which is not allowed by `Pin`. The cleaned error message looks like:

```rust
error[E0599]: no method named `into_actor` found for type `Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = Result<Vec<ResultType>, Box<dyn Error>>> + Send>>` in the current scope
   --> src/app_socket.rs:194:26
    |
194 |                         .into_actor(&self)
    |                          ^^^^^^^^^^ method not found in `Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = Result<Vec<ResultType>, Box<dyn Error>>> + Send>>`
    |
    = note: the method `into_actor` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
            `&dyn Future<Output = Result<std::vec::Vec<ResultType>, std::boxed::Box<dyn std::error::Error>>> + Send : WrapFuture<_>`
            `&dyn Future<Output = Result<std::vec::Vec<ResultType>, std::boxed::Box<dyn std::error::Error>>> + Send : WrapStream<_>`
            `&mut dyn Future<Output = Result<std::vec::Vec<ResultType>, std::boxed::Box<dyn std::error::Error>>> + Send : WrapFuture<_>`
            `&mut dyn Future<Output = Result<std::vec::Vec<ResultType>, std::boxed::Box<dyn std::error::Error>>> + Send : WrapStream<_>`
            `&mut Pin<std::boxed::Box<dyn Future<Output = Result<std::vec::Vec<ResultType>, std::boxed::Box<dyn std::error::Error>>> + Send>> : WrapFuture<_>`
            `&mut Pin<std::boxed::Box<dyn Future<Output = Result<std::vec::Vec<ResultType>, std::boxed::Box<dyn std::error::Error>>> + Send>> : WrapStream<_>`
            `&Pin<std::boxed::Box<dyn Future<Output = Result<std::vec::Vec<ResultType>, std::boxed::Box<dyn std::error::Error>>> + Send>> : WrapFuture<_>`
            `&Pin<std::boxed::Box<dyn Future<Output = Result<std::vec::Vec<ResultType>, std::boxed::Box<dyn std::error::Error>>> + Send>> : WrapStream<_>`
            `dyn Future<Output = Result<std::vec::Vec<ResultType>, std::boxed::Box<dyn std::error::Error>>> + Send : WrapFuture<_>`
            `dyn Future<Output = Result<std::vec::Vec<ResultType>, std::boxed::Box<dyn std::error::Error>>> + Send : WrapStream<_>`
            `Pin<std::boxed::Box<dyn Future<Output = Result<std::vec::Vec<ResultType>, std::boxed::Box<dyn std::error::Error>>> + Send>> : WrapFuture<_>`
            `Pin<std::boxed::Box<dyn Future<Output = Result<std::vec::Vec<ResultType>, std::boxed::Box<dyn std::error::Error>>> + Send>> : WrapStream<_>`
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What do you need to `Pin` a future for? I'd understand pinning the generator of the future for pinning the future itself feels very esoteric.

Comment: That happens because of the async-trait crate. See https://github.com/dtolnay/async-trait#explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual problem was not that the future was pinned, but that it implemented the wrong future trait.

[This section on Pinning](https://rust-lang.github.io/async-book/04_pinning/01_chapter.html) explains that `poll` is implemented for `Pin<ref T: Future>`.

Hence, the `into_actor` signature `self: impl Future -> WrapFuture<_>` was fine. The problem was that the `async` method returned a future implementing `std::future::Future` while `into_actor` expected `futures01::future::Future`.

Calling `.compat()` on the future before calling `.into_actor` fixes the problem.

See [this post](https://rust-lang-nursery.github.io/futures-rs/blog/2019/04/18/compatibility-layer.html) for more detail about converting futures.